# Controller 'alertForm', required by directive 'loginForm', can't be found! in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> Controller 'alertForm', required by directive 'loginForm', can't be
>   found!

```
angular.module('jobsApp')
    .directive('alertForm', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/directives/alert/alertForm.html',
            restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                   topic: '=topic',
                   description: '=description'
                }
            }
    })
    .directive('loginForm', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/directives/loginForm/loginForm.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^alertForm',
            scope: {
                successCallback: '&',
                errorCallback: '&',
                emailField: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, alertFormModelCtrl) {
                scope.alertFormModel = alertFormModel
            },
            controller: function ($rootScope, $scope, authenticationService) {
                $scope.loginFormData = {};
                $scope.inProgress = false;
                $scope.onLogin = function (form) {
                    if (form.$valid) {
                        $scope.inProgress = true;
                        authenticationService.loginUser('password', $scope.loginFormData).then(function () {
                            $scope.inProgress = false;
                        }, function (err) {
                            $scope.inProgress = false;
                            if (err.message) {
                                //$scope.alertFormCtrl.topic = "asdffasfd";
                                alert(err.message);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML where the directive is used?

Comment: @MaartenBicknese i've edited my question as adding what you said.

Comment: I was actually looking for the HTML parsed by the browser and JS. something like `<login-form success-callback="callbackFunction()"></login-form>`

Comment: i don't think that error is relevant to that case.

Comment: Sorry, I think I might have been confusing you.
Somewhere in your HTML you've used the `login-form` element. This element would use your directive and in its turn trigger the error.

I'm looking for the HTML where you have used your directive element. Preferably with the parent element as well (to give some context to the problem).

Comment: Please post your html code where you are using this directive.

Comment: I've edited post. (Using *.jade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive requires the `alertForm` controller to be present in the scope of the `loginForm`. You'll either have to add it to the current scope. Or prefix the requirement with a `^` to search in the parent scope.

From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive:

> The `myPane` directive has a `require` option with value `^myTabs`. When a directive uses this option, $compile will throw an error unless the specified controller is found. The ^ prefix means that this directive searches for the controller on its parents (without the `^` prefix, the directive would look for the controller on just its own element).

Comment: Can you check my edited answer? Still encounter same error even I put regarding your document.

Comment: The problem occurs at HTML/Jade level, not within the JavaScript. Are you trying to extend the functionality of `loginForm` with `alertForm`?

Comment: btw, I don't know think so it's on Jade level. Yap, I'm trying to extend.